# Data logging in Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, database

I have made a C++ program which communicates with an RFM95 LoRa module and listens to messages from a various transmitters nearby. Those transmitters transmits sensors' data like temperature, humidity, moisture, brightness, noise polution etc.

I want to save those data into the Raspberry Pi. The internal microsd card would be perfect choice if that is feasible.

There are only two ways come to my mind.
1) A noSQL database and 2) the simple method of storing data into a log file (e.g. myData.txt file).

What would be the best solution for that?
I'm using Raspberry Pi 2 Model B, with C++ and Raspbian.

Comment: What are the RPi pins accepting the data? I2C, SPI, UART? When this is recognised you would need an C/C++ or python script to save to file or selected database.

Comment: I think the hardware communication interface is irrelevant as my program is already running and the data are printed on the screen. The question was about how to store data. Apart from that, all those RFM95 modules I've seen on the internet work with SPI and so does mine.

Comment: If hardware is irrelevant for your question then this is not the right place to ask. You should ask at https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have to be NoSQL then the simplest option is SQLite3. The only restriction with SQLite3 is one writer. You can have multiple readers.

I've been logging data from a BMP180 temp/pressure sensor every three minutes for three years. There's some code on Github at [../DougieLawson/RaspberryPi/tree/master/bmp180](https://github.com/DougieLawson/RaspberryPi/tree/master/bmp180)

That stuff runs on a RPi Zero, the data is on a NFS shared hard disk.

Recently I re-wrote the python code for that data logging as C++. [I'll push that to Github today.]

Comment: You may want to disclose your [affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) with the project explicitly.